# Animation is not working in Emulater

Tags: android, animation, android-emulator

i am enable to load animation in Emulater..Its working fine with any real device..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imgView;
    private Animation animation;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.grow);
        animation.setRepeatCount(50); // Repeat animation infinitely
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); 

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imgView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                imgView.startAnimation(animation);      



                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyWebView.class);
                        startActivity(it);

                    }
                }, 5000);


            }
        });
    }
```

and my anim xml file is following

```
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="360"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="50" />
```

Comment: nope..!! getting no errors.! sometimes getting just slidly effect..but not fully working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you Might have Disabled Animations in Emulator:
Check that:

Settings>Display>Animation..

Hope that helps your Problem

Comment: I check .. but its already ON..m getting three option "No Animations","Some Animations" & "All Animations"... nd its selected in "All Animations"..

Answer (score 3):

For anyone running into similar issues when using `ObjectAnimator`, in my case I had to enable the developer settings on the emulator and then go into "Settings" > "Developer options" > "Drawing" section

In this "Drawing" section you'll find different options for each animation type, in my case the "Animator duration scale" was off, after setting it to "1x" I started seeing the animations on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

UI tests could disable animations on emulator or device and if you want them back you need to enable `Developer options` manually and turn them back on in `Drawing` section one by one.

Or maybe you can enable them back again by running ui tests while changing in your app module `build.gradle` :

```
android {
    ...
    testOptions {
       ...
       animationsDisabled = false
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```